# Fonts in EmojiTextView do not work

Tags: android, fonts

Platform: Android App Development using Android Studio (Java).

To support Emoji's , I am using the EmojiTextView control (Code snippet below).

Even when I set the FontFamily in XML, this control does not show the Font in the App. It show the default font.

```
<android.support.text.emoji.widget.EmojiTextView
    android:id="@+id/TextView_BotRespText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fontFamily="@font/open_sans"
    android:text="Bot Response Text"
    android:textStyle="normal"
    android:visibility="visible" />
```

I went and changed EmojiTextView to EmojiAppCompatTextView and it worked.

```
    <android.support.text.emoji.widget.EmojiAppCompatTextView
        android:id="@+id/TextView_BotRespText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fontFamily="@font/open_sans"
        android:text="Bot Response Text"
        android:textStyle="normal"
        android:visibility="visible" />
```

Can someone throw light on difference between EmojiTextView and EmojiAppCompatTextView?